# Mutilanguage text inpunt directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, input, internationalization

Is there an angular directive for text inputs to enter value in different languages?

For example something like Liferay multilanguage form fields

Use case example:

User can edit value using text input in different languages, then the value is stored in a JSON like

```
{"en_EN" : "Value in English", "it_IT" : "Value in Italian", "fr_FR" : "Value in French"
}
```

Comment: You can take a look at [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/), it's a module to create multilanguage app

Comment: As I understand it provides user the translated strings. Is that correct? I need something where the user can translate strings on his own

Comment: Yes, the user can change the language of your app. So you want something like [google translate](https://translate.google.fr/?hl=fr), where the user can translate what he write in an input ?

Comment: If you could please provide a real example, cause I can't find what you're talking about. Or a link to Liferay where there are multilanguage form fields.

Comment: I need the user the possibility to enter the value in an input field in different languages. Then I will store the values as a JSON object like
{
"en_EN":"Value in English",
"it_IT":"Value in Italian",
"fr_FR":"Value in French"
}